# Swap a 0 under the cursor with a 1 and vice versa

Tags: key-bindings, substitute

Assume that, in normal mode, the character under the cursor is either 0 or 1.

I want that, upon pressing a key (say <kbd>F6</kbd>), it is swapped to the other one.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78183747/is-there-a-way-to-flip-the-bit-under-your-cursor-in-nvim

Comment: @romainl This also is interesting

Comment: I admit the thought "didn't I already answer this question a couple of days ago?" crossed my mind... followed by panicked scrolling to see where my answer had gone :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function! One2Zero()
  let c = getline('.')[col('.')-1]
  if c == '1'
    return 'r0'
  elseif c == '0'
    return 'r1'
  else
    return "\<F6>"
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <F6> One2Zero()
```

Comment: as you write it, I get an error. If I change `getcol` into `col`, then it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have corrected the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can increment and decrement numbers with C-a and C-x. The sequences `r0` and `r1` will also work.